# Why are implicit conversion not allowed in prefect forwarding?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, implicit

Suppose we have the following code:

```
void ff(wchar_t*)
{

}

template<typename T>
void ffc(T&& a)
{
    ff(std::forward<T>(a));
}
```

Why is the call `ff(0)` allowed, but `ffc(0)` is not?

Comment: looks like your implementation doesn't consider `(int&&)0` as a null pointer constant.  At a minimum, only actual literal zeros (e.g. `0`, `00`, `0u`) are required to be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of `ffc(0)` T will be deduced as *int*  since `0` is a integer literal whose type is *int* and there is no valid implicit conversion from int to *wchar_t ** even without the forwarding, so the following case won't work either:

```
template<typename T>
void ffc_no_forward(T&& a)
{
    ff(a);
}
```

whereas in the first case `0` is a null pointer constant and therefore is perfectly valid conversion to *wchar_t **.

We can see from the draft C++14 standard(`N4140`) section `4.10` Pointer conversions [conv.ptr] that an *int* with zero value is not sufficient it must be an integer literal or must be a prvalue of *std::nullptr_t*:

> A null pointer constant is an integer literal (2.14.2) with value zero or a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t.
>   A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type
>   and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion
>   is called a null pointer conversion.[...]

In C++11 the wording allowed an *integral constant expression* that evaluated to zero but in this case actually does not matter since as T.C. points out `std::forward<T>()` could not be a constant expression since the parameter to a function can not be a constant expression either.

Comment: It'd be good to indicate which document you reference; since the rules about null pointer constants changed between C++11 and C++14

Comment: There seem to be bugs in even the latest versions of g++ and clang regarding this conversion, too . For example, g++ 5.2 accepts `ff(1-1)` when it shouldn't under C++14.

Comment: @M.M gcc `6.0.0` does not allow it, so looks like a fixed bug.

Comment: @T.C. indeed, I knew I had seen that defect before but finding it was tricky looking backwards from the changed wording.

Comment: CWG DR 903 (the "literal zero only" rule) doesn't really matter here, since `std::forward<T>(a)`, involving a function parameter, can't possibly be a constant expression, so it isn't a null pointer constant under any version of the standard.